# Keep text format on copy/paste quill.js

Tags: quill

im using the [quill.js](http://quilljs.com/) "Quill Rich Text Editor" for my project.
And i want to programm a "Code" Button, to style a specific code content.

But a code functionality in the editor requires to keep the text format.
Like the `<pre>` tag in HTML.

But when i copy some "code" text in the editor, tabulators or multible spaces will be removed. 
Even if i add "white-space: pre !important" to the editor class.

```
.ql-editor {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 300px;
  min-height: 100%;
  outline: none;
  tab-size: 4;
  white-space: pre !important;
}
```

Have someone the same problems, or anyone know a solution for this problem?

regards

Answer (score 0):

Code formatting is not supported yet so Quill is converting the content to the subset of formats it does know.

Answer (score 0):

Quill can handle multible spaces, but not tabs. So there is no way to replace tabs with multible spaces?

regards